# Air-gapped .NET code-signed application will not install/run

Tags: c#, .net, windows, security, certificate

We recently updated our applications to make use of SHA-256 code-signing with a new certificate. The assemblies are strong name signed using the `Sign the assembly` option in Visual Studio 2015. The post build event in Visual Studio runs two `signtool.exe` processes to sign both in SHA-256 and for the legacy SHA-1 certificate:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe" 
sign /f "<mystrongName.pfx>" /p "<password>" /t 
<timestampURL> "$(TargetPath)"

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\signtool.exe" 
sign /f "<mystrongName.pfx>" /p "<password>" /fd sha256 /tr 
<timestampURL> /td sha256 /as /v "$(TargetPath)"
```

Finally we use Advanced Installer as the installation packager and that too is code-signed on the `Digital Signature` page using the certificate and timestamp as per the .exe signature.

The final setup file installs and runs on Internet connected Windows machines as you would expect. You can see the certificate is assigned and valid, as well as the certificate chain through the properties of both the setup.exe and the runtime when installed. Furthermore, Windows recognizes the application as from a trusted source and displays the appropriate verified publisher details.

Our customer-base is largely global 100 companies and most of the deployments will be occurring in air-gapped networks. In one of our fist updated deployments in this environment, the certificate could not be verified preventing the installer from completing.

This made sense, because the Windows (2012 server R2) machines were isolated from the Internet and, due to company policies, had `Turn off Automatic Root Certificates` set to `Enabled`. This setting can be found in the `Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Internet Communication Management -> Internet Communication Settings` folder of the MMC application (you need the certificates plugin installed).

When testing on our local test-bed, even machines not connected to the Internet would install the certificates from the setup utility if the above registry setting was the default (`Disabled`). We could replicate the issue by changing the policy setting to match the customers' (`Enabled`).

As a workaround, we manually downloaded the Certificate Authorities root certificate and installed it as a Trusted Root Certificate and the install would proceed normally.

When we presented this workaround to the customer, the installation still failed despite the Certificate Authorities root certificate being present in the Trusted Root Certificates of the machine.

The Certificate Authority customer service team recommended that we drop the timestamp from the signing process to allow the install to proceed - and that's the only help they offered (that's another story). However, this means that once the code-signing certificate expires, the application will either cease to run or will present unverified publisher errors.

I'm not totally convinced that this will fix the problem either, because when we tested locally the certificate was still found by the installer and allowed the installation to proceed when the Certificate Authorities root certificate was installed manually.

What I am unable to do is replicate the customers environment to exactly reproduce the problem (which doesn't help). It is almost as if Windows is bypassing the local machine's Trusted Root Certificates store. I am assuming that if this is possible it would be so that Windows can verify against a central root certificate store.

Is this even possible to set up in Windows? If so, where would I find either documentation on this or how is this done?

Am I missing something in the code-signing steps or in my understanding of what should be happening on the installing machine while it is checking the certificate?

I am at a loss as to what to do to get this installer working. What I can't afford to do is keep going back to the customer to get them to keep testing our installs. First-off it's really not the right process to debug, as the supplying vendor it isn't the customers problem to solve, but more importantly, I need our team to understand what is causing this and how to remedy it correctly.

Ideally I don't what to drop the timestamp if I don't have to because down the road this will cause new problems if the software doesn't get upgraded before the certificate expires.

Any and all help much appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't trust end users that they're able to install the certificates correctly - that should be automated. Also there seems to be more certificates you need to install locally (I'm refering to this link I found: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio-in-offline-environment)

Comment: I think your solution is indeed to install root certs manually (if the automatic update is disabled for some reason). So you should concentrate on that. Unfortunately, there are many reasons why a root cert cannot be installed (google on 'root certificate install fails'...), but it should be a customer by customer issue. You must find why it fails (with proper logs, traces, ask customer to send it, etc.). In the end, disabling the automatic update is the customer's responsability (https://serverfault.com/questions/752146), so he should be ok to help you make the manual install work.

Comment: @Ondrej - as much as limiting the end users to what they should or shouldn't be able to do is desirable, unfortunately when dealing with billion dollar corporations you have very little influence over deployment environments as a software developer. Looking into the link you added now. Thanks for the info - will let you know if it helps.

Comment: @Simon - The root certs can be installed (ie the deployment team has enough has sufficient privilege at the security level to add the root certs), but they don't seem to be used as part of the verification process. Your suggestion on the logs and traces has me looking down that path to see if anything gives a reason why its failing. I think between Ondrej's and your responses the answer lies somewhere in making sure *all* the required certs are installed and they are being validated correctly. I am thinking that maybe an intermediate certificate is missing.

Comment: Are you certain that (1) the certificates that are being installed are placed in the correct user / service. (2) the certificates are readable to the installer once installed? **Yes. You could do this all programmatically.**

Comment: The root cert that signed your cert was installed, but did you check that the root cert the timestamp server is signed with was also installed? That could be a different CA.

Comment: @Svek - the certificates are definitely installed in the correct user/service. Verified this doing a replication locally in our test bed and against the customer's install. However, not certain that certificates are readable to the installer at this point (assuming because of policy settings). Currently looking into programmatically checking as your comment suggests.

Comment: @Scott - good point. I think we might even have 3 certificates in total to install which includes the intermediary as well. Waiting on an answer form the customer to verify. The waiting game sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one reason a certificate cannot be validated in an airgapped environment may be that revocation cannot be verified. As you may know, a certificate can be revoked, and there are two different protocols to check if it is, CRL and OCSP. Both require network access to the CA that issued the certificate.

Whether revocations are actually checked is governed by policies as described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753863(v=ws.11).aspx), and this may cause your issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and link. I am pretty convinced that policies are instrumental (although not necessarily exclusively the problem) to the issues here given the inability to exactly replicate at this point in our test bed. Reading through your linked page now...

Comment: this helped with some tests, currently waiting on the results of those to see if this was the cause of the problem. Fingers crossed!

Comment: In light of this potential answer, it might be possible for you to install the revocation list on the devices in question, that way the revocation can be checked locally without requiring access to the root CA. I had the same issue with a self-minted cert for a test server - not sure if this helps but installing the CRL worked for me.